# Not able to assign the value to a variable inside Angular factory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

if the variable is an array , then I am able to push the object inside it and get the value inside controller but in case of assigning the object directly to that variable , I am not able to do it

Please anyone help me to achieve this.

Here is the Fiddle Link

Angular Code:

```
//angular.js example for factory vs service
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('testFactory', function(){
     var countF={};//= [{abc:'aaa'}];
    return {

        getCount : function () {

            return countF;
        },
        incrementCount:function(){
          //countF.push({aaaa:'jshfdkjsf'});
           countF={aaaa:'jshfdkjsf'};
            //return countF;
        }
    }               
});

function FactoryCtrl($scope,testFactory)
{
    $scope.countFactory = testFactory.getCount();
    $scope.clickF = function () {
       testFactory.incrementCount();
       // console.log($scope.countFactory);
    };
}
```

HTML Code:

```
<div ng-controller="FactoryCtrl">

    <!--  this is never updated after count is changed! -->
    <p> This is my countFactory variable : {{countFactory}}</p>

    <p> This is my updated after click variable : {{countF}}</p>

    <button ng-click="clickF()" >Factory ++ </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Because using an array shares the memeory reference with the same data, reassigning a variable, instead, loses it.

Comment: you missed linked in 'Here is the Fiddle Link' :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **problem** is in this code -

```
 incrementCount:function(){
        //countF.push({aaaa:'jshfdkjsf'});
        countF={aaaa:'jshfdkjsf'};
        //return countF;
 }
```

here you are not initizalizing aaa property of countF object you are recreating it

**Initialization** - `countF = {};`

**Adding a property** -

```
  right `countF.aaa = "value";`

  wrong `countF = { aaa : 'value' }`
```

**Solution** -

```
incrementCount:function(){
    countF.aaaa = 'jshfdkjsf';
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Like said in comment, problem is in references, but here is hack:

```
//angular.js example for factory vs service
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.factory('testFactory', function(){
    var countF={};//= [{abc:'aaa'}];
    var getCountF = function(){
        return countF;
    };
    var setCountF = function(arg){
        countF = arg;
    };
    return {

    getCount : getCountF,
    setCount : setCountF,

    incrementCount:function(){
        //countF.push({aaaa:'jshfdkjsf'});
        countF={aaaa:'jshfdkjsf'};
        //return countF;
    }
}
});

function FactoryCtrl($scope,testFactory)
{
    $scope.countFactory = testFactory.getCount();
    $scope.clickF = function () {
        testFactory.incrementCount();
        // console.log($scope.countFactory);
    };
}
```

[Quick Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apimenov93/8fj6e4hf/1/)